# Tracking IP Address in NodeJS, Receiving Two Numbers

Tags: node.js, networking, ip

I'm tracking user IP addresses that make requests to a specific endpoint.

This is how I'm tracking the IP address:

```
const ipAddress = req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || 
    req.connection.remoteAddress || 
    req.socket.remoteAddress ||
    (req.connection.socket ? req.connection.socket.remoteAddress : null)
```

When the result is recorded, I get a string with two numbers.

For example: `XX.XX.XX.117, XXX.XX.XX.234`

What are each of the two numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the request is forwarded from a proxy server to your endpoint then you'll get more than 1 IP address from `req.headers['x-forwarded-for']`. The first one will be the client IP and the following IP addresses will be the IPs of proxies in order. In your case, there is only one proxy between the client and your server, so you are seeing only two IPs. In short, the first one is the client IP and the second one is proxy IP.

For more reference on [X-Forwarded-For](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Forwarded-For)